# Manual Password Verification ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-identity

I have an existing site that I want to upgrade to MVC 5. I’d like to take advantage of the new ASP.NET Identity. There doesn’t seem to be a direct way of migrating my existing users i.e. copying passwords and salts to the new database scheme. A previous question I had about this suggested capturing the passwords as users log in and migrating them to the new authentication system one at a time.

For this to work I need to manually authentic the users of the old system. After some googling it seems the following code should work:

```
public static string EncodePassword(string pass, string salt)
{
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(pass);
    byte[] src = Convert.FromBase64String(salt);
    byte[] dst = new byte[src.Length + bytes.Length];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(src, 0, dst, 0, src.Length);
    Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 0, dst, src.Length, bytes.Length);
    HashAlgorithm algorithm = HashAlgorithm.Create("SHA1");
    byte[] inArray = algorithm.ComputeHash(dst);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(inArray);
}
```

But  I am having no luck. Here is a password, password hash, and salt from the old membership table:

```
Password: password
Hash: A1sWiqXLSFx892gfZli5Mn85hZqjW1Vg6BAQ12S7B40=
Salt: Hou1PWslN7MQ+PjFLlW5Xg==
Format: 1
```

And from web.config:

```
<membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="Ultra" />
    <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="Ultra" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

Can someone explain what algorithm I should use to manually check this password?

Comment: Can you use Membership.ValidateUser?

Comment: That’s what I use on the old site. I don’t want to wire up the old membership plumbing on the new site. I thought just manually checking it would be cleaner. The new site uses UserManager.FindAsync()

Comment: I think that is going to be the easiest way to migrate.

Comment: Take a look at this QA on wiring up a custom password hasher in ASP.NET Identity [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19957176/asp-net-identity-password-hashing].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to use an algorithm based on this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/19184807/1626624

Here’s the algorithm for hashing passwords.

```
    public static string EncodePassword(string pass, string salt)
    {
        var passBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(pass);
        var saltBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(salt);
        var keyedHashAlgorithm = (KeyedHashAlgorithm)HashAlgorithm.Create("HMACSHA256");
        var keyBytes = new byte[keyedHashAlgorithm.Key.Length];
        var num1 = 0;

        while (true)
        {
            if (num1 >= keyBytes.Length)
            {
                break;
            }

            var num2 = Math.Min(saltBytes.Length, keyBytes.Length - num1);

            Buffer.BlockCopy(saltBytes, 0, keyBytes, num1, num2);
            num1 = num1 + num2;
        }

        keyedHashAlgorithm.Key = keyBytes;

        return Convert.ToBase64String(keyedHashAlgorithm.ComputeHash(passBytes));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

MembershipUser user = Membership.Provider.GetUser(Txtboxemail.Text, false);
 if (Membership.ValidateUser(Txtboxemail.Text, pass.Text)){}

May be you are in need of this

Answer (score 0):

Try using the tutorial [Migrating an Existing Website from SQL Membership to ASP.NET Identity](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/migrations/migrating-an-existing-website-from-sql-membership-to-aspnet-identity). It has even details on password hashing.